# Wordpress Functions Switching From DAP to WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have come across an issue past my level of expertise and am hoping for some help.  I am switching my subscription portal on Wordpress from DAP to WooCommerce and have an issue with a section of php in the template.  I have included the part in question.  Basically I need to change the DAP user and session calls to call up the WooCommerce user and session.

Any help would be appreciated. Below is part of the code in question. Thanks in advance.

```
        <?php $session = Dap_Session::getSession();
            $user = $session->getUser();
            $userProducts = Dap_UsersProducts::loadProducts($user->getId()); ?>


        <div class="locker-programs">
            <h2>Training Programs</h2>

            <div class="locker-grid">
                <?php if ( Dap_Session::isLoggedIn() ) {
                        //get userid
                        $session = Dap_Session::getSession();
                        $user = $session->getUser();
                        $user = Dap_User::loadUserById($user->getId());
```